# Overflow summing elements in a for loop, but std::reduce works

Tags: c++, for-loop, reduce

I was doing a comparison when summing elements of a vector using for loop and std::reduce, but the loop leads to an overflow, and I am struggling to find out why.

Here is the code:

```cpp
void red(std::vector<unsigned> &v){
    std::cout << std::reduce(v.begin(), v.end(), 0) << std::endl;
}

void sum(std::vector<unsigned> &v){
    unsigned long long s = 0;
    for (auto i : v)
        s += i;
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Calling the functions:

```cpp
std::vector<unsigned> v(std::stoi(argv[1]));
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
sum(v);
red(v);
```

I expected the same result in both cases, but for some big values the loop generate strange results.

Up to 10000 both gives the same (right) value.

For 100000, "red" prints the right value, but "sum" prints 704982704.

I even tried to do:

```
void red(std::vector<unsigned> &v){
    unsigned long long s = std::reduce(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

But nothing changes.

Comment: *reduces gives the right value, but the loop gives 704982704* Is it a right statement?

Comment: Note that the two implementations diverge exactly when the cap is `N = 65537 = 2**16 +1`, which is when the sum `N*(N-1)/2` overflows a 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got it backward: your loop code (`sum()`) gives the right answers, but your use of `std::reduce()` is broken and so (`red()`) gives wrong answers.

Try it for `69999`:

```
 2449895001 (sum())
-1845072295 (red())
```

This happens because you passed a signed integer `0` to `std::reduce()`.  You should pass an unsigned one instead, such as `0uLL`.

Answer (score 1):

The returned type of [`std::reduce(3)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce) is the type of the `init`. You pass `int` 0, you get overflow.

```
std::reduce(v.begin(), v.end(), 0ULL);
//                               ^^^
```